# Mypy "class module" annotation

Tags: python, types, mypy

I have a function `load_config` that loads and returns a python module:

```
import imp

def load_config(path: str):
    return imp.load_source('config', path)

print(type(load_config('config.py')))
```

This snippet prints `<class 'module'>`.

How do I annotate `load_config` return value with Mypy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct annotation is:

```
import imp
import types

def load_config(path: str) -> types.ModuleType:
  return imp.load_source('config', path)
```

However, there's an [open issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1498) to fix it in the current version of mypy.